# PHP CodeIgniter multiple LEFT OUTER join in on query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, left-join

I'm using PHP CodeIgniter to query from my Database. I need to use multiple LEFT OUTER joins. The join uses multiple conditions (I'm not sure it is supported as of the bug). My query results have the same value for both parameters I want to fetch:

Query:

```
$this->db->select('anonymous.*,
    count(items_likes.id) as all_likes, count(items_comments.id) as all_comments');
    $this->db->from('anonymous');
    $this->db->where('anonymous.fid', $feed_id);

    $this->db->group_by('anonymous.id');

    $this->db->join('all_users', 'all_users.id = anonymous.uid', 'left outer');
    $this->db->join('images', 'images.ud = anonymous.uid AND images.fid = anonymous.fid', 'left outer');
    $this->db->join('items_likes', 'items_likes.uid = anonymous.uid AND items_likes.fid = anonymous.fid', 'left outer');

    $this->db->join('items_comments', 'items_comments.uid = anonymous.uid AND items_comments.fid = anonymous.fid', 'left outer');

    $list = $this->db->get()->result();
```

*anonymous: is a table with unregistered users*

*fid: Is the feed id*

*images: Is a table of all the images that were uploaded to the feed*

*items_likes: Is all the users' likes per image*

*items_comments: Is all the users' comments per image*

---

The problem is that all_comments always return the **same** value as all_likes.
I'm not sure if the multiple LEFT-OUTER joins are the problem or maybe the fact that I'm using multiple conditions in every join statement i.e.

> items_comments.uid = anonymous.uid AND items_comments.fid = anonymous.fid

The log result:

```
"all_likes":"12","all_comments":"12"
```

although I have 12 likes, the comments should be 3

If I write the query as follows the result is ok:

```
$this->db->select('anonymous.*,
(SELECT count( items_likes.id ) FROM items_likes WHERE items_likes.uid = anonymous.uid AND items_likes.fid = anonymous.fid) as all_likes, 
(SELECT count( items_comments.id ) FROM items_comments WHERE items_comments.uid = anonymous.uid AND items_comments.fid = anonymous.fid) as all_comments');
$this->db->from('anonymous');
$this->db->where('anonymous.fid', $feed_id);

$this->db->group_by('anonymous.id');

$this->db->join('all_users', 'all_users.id = anonymous.uid', 'left outer');
$this->db->join('images', 'images.ud = anonymous.uid AND images.fid = anonymous.fid', 'left outer');
//$this->db->join('items_likes', 'items_likes.uid = anonymous.uid AND items_likes.fid = anonymous.fid', 'left outer');

//$this->db->join('items_comments', 'items_comments.uid = anonymous.uid AND items_comments.fid = anonymous.fid', 'left outer');

$list = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Left outer join produces a complete set of records from Table A, with
>   the matching records (where available) in Table B. If there is no
>   match, the right side will contain null.

You need to add the records which contain NULL

add this where clause to your query:

```
$this->db->->where('items_comments.uid IS NULL')
```

more info on joins [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Did you mean: IS NOT NULL

Comment: no, if you look at the diagram I linked explaining the left outer join, you'll see table B is the comments which were made on Table A posts. So after joining, you want to exclude all the NULLs (no comments) from table B, to get the list of elements in table A with a comment (B). I don't know your table scheme, you might need to adapt this, but this is the concept...

Comment: Thanks, I’ll check it and advise